# HTC One E8 phone app lists just the top contact while dialling

Tags: contacts, htc, htc-sense, htc-one

I am beginning to use this new device of mine, one major downside is that when I try to call someone, in my old HTC desire, I just used to type in the name and it used to list all matches, most of the times I used to select the second or third name in the list, now I have lost that flexibility.

What are my options now, is there an app I can install that will show all the matching contacts rather than the top one contact that I get now (it almost feels suffocating).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after struggling for about a week, I found that selecting "Show Large Dial pad" from the menu in the phone app showed the list making it possible to call others as well.

I now need to find how I can see more than two at a time in the background list and shall update this answer once I find.